# How to append object in postgresql jsonb field while update

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I want to update my jsonb field it store array of object.
i want to add new object in it.

```
CREATE TABLE justjson ( id INTEGER, doc JSONB);
INSERT INTO justjson VALUES ( 1, '[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "age": "22"
  },
  {
    "name": "def",
    "age": "23"
  }
]');
```

then value like

```
select doc from justjson;

doc
[{"age": "22", "name": "abc"}, {"age": "23", "name": "def"}]
```

Now I want to append new object in this jsonb

```
{"age": "45", "name": "xyz"}
```

How can i update this field?

my output such as

```
doc
    [{"age": "22", "name": "abc"}, {"age": "23", "name": "def"},{"age": "45", "name": "xyz"}]
```

Comment: [Look here for](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) *Concatenate two jsonb values into a new jsonb value.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the concatenation operator `||` to append an element to an array:

```
UPDATE justjson
SET doc = doc || '{"age": "45", "name": "xyz"}'::jsonb
WHERE is = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Such an ardent appeal cannot remain unheard.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe
How can I update in jsonb such as i want to set age by name 
Ex. where name = xyz set age = 46
in above table